# How to sort_by in descending order without reverse in jq

Tags: sorting, jq, reverse

When you have a columns and want to sort by multiple columns in various orders - you will start chaining reverses

my jq sort_by is stable, but if i need to sort by descending - I have to do double reverse, which i dont like

```
sort_by(.person) # first sort in ascending
| reverse | sort_by(.city) | reverse # then sort by in descending
```

In order to keep both `city` descending and `person` ascending, (but by city)  - I feel like I need double reverse, so this api does not looks good, in terms of performance for advanced sorting.

Do you know any workaround, not using double reverse?

Comment: jq-1.6 does not have the option to specify such a sort option. You need to reverse, if you want the opposite

Comment: i wish to have sort/2, but `jq: error: sort_by/2 is not defined at <top-level>`

Comment: @Inian 1.5 had? so i just need to write custom function, to have second optional parameter, and it will become incompatible with jqplay? No other way, right?

Comment: I was indicating, that as of today, such an option didn't exist.

Comment: It's a shame jq doesn't have a custom sort method. the function would at least encapsulate the complexity.

Answer (score 3):

More of an idea than a good solution, but you could sort by negative codepoints obtained by using `explode`. At least there's no `reverse` involved, and only one call to `sort_by` is needed for all criteria.

```bash
sort_by(.person, (.city | [-explode[]]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, good idea, but in a project I use query injection, so in some cases I just have to pipe.. also we don't know for sure if it's string numeric or boolean property, such query constructor will be hard on itself. Better way is to try extend the standart. For now I can simulate sort_by/2 with a external function plugin to the library that we use

Comment: @xakepp35 I totally agree that provided builtins would be preferrable. Let me only add real quick that you can also implement generic type distinction quite easily, e.g. `(strings | [-explode[]]), -numbers, (booleans | not)` etc. Also not being the best coding style, but still doable.

Answer (score 1):

`reverse_merge_sort_by(f)` as defined here is a stable reverse merge-sort, where the primary order is determined by f:

```
# If both the input arrays $x and $y are reverse sorted according to f,
# then the result will also be reverse sorted with stability maintained
def reverse_merge_by($x; $y; f):
  def m:  # state: [i, j, array]  (i and j being indices into x and y respectively)
    .[0] as $i | .[1] as $j
    | if $i == -1 then $y[:$j + 1] + .[2]
      elif $j == -1 then $x[:$i + 1] + .[2]
      elif ($x[$i]|f) < ($y[$j]|f)  # to ensure stability, one must not use <= here
      then [$i - 1, $j,     [$x[$i]] + .[2] ] | m
      else [$i,     $j - 1, [$y[$j]] + .[2] ] | m
      end
      ;
   [($x|length - 1), ($y|length -1), []] | m;

def reverse_merge_sort_by(f):
  if length <= 1 then .
  else (length/2 |floor) as $len
  | reverse_merge_by( .[:$len] | reverse_merge_sort_by(f);
                      .[$len:] | reverse_merge_sort_by(f); f )
  end;
```

For convenience, you may want to define an alias, e.g.

```
def rs(f): reverse_merge_sort_by(f);
```

This has been tested with both the C and Go implementations (jq and gojq).

---

Example:

```
[[2,1], [2,2], [1,1],[1,2],[1,0]]
 | . == reverse_merge_sort_by(.[0])
```

yields `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, nice work, but I prefer native implementations.. and we have a liiitle problem here. Or i just lack information. Can you write a gojq func? ;-)

Comment: I mean that `reverse_merge_sort_by(.[0])` - that `.[0]` part has a little problem if you will try to express it as compile.WithFunction thing in gojq - it will yield passing `[2,1]` argument - with gojq i have a problem writing external `map` or `sort_by`-like function.. do you know an answer for that? I dont think jq, especially gojq will be JIT-ed anytime soon, so prefer solution in go